# Recursively calling a promise based javascript function for a web scraper to check for next pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, promise

I'm building an Ebay web scraper as a side project and I need to know how to call a promise based function many times to get all the seller's items on multiple pages until I reach the end of his items.

Basically, using Javascript and Node.js, if the seller has only 1 page of items, I scrape it and everything is fine.

Things get complicated for me when he has multiple pages and I need to call the promise function multiple times and returning the links to every page. I tried promise loops, I've tried recursion, and I've tried async/await. Nothing seems to work.

I will include a code snippet for you guys:

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const options = {
    url : 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=&_sacat=0&_udlo=&_udhi=&_ftrt=901&_ftrv=1&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=15&_stpos=29582&_sargn=-1%26saslc%3D1&_salic=1&_fss=1&_fsradio=%26LH_SpecificSeller%3D1&_saslop=1&_sasl=brickearth&_sop=12&_dmd=1&_ipg=50&_fosrp=1',
    //url : 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=&_sacat=0&_udlo=&_udhi=&_ftrt=901&_ftrv=1&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=15&_stpos=29582&_sargn=-1%26saslc%3D1&_salic=1&_fss=1&_fsradio=%26LH_SpecificSeller%3D1&_saslop=1&_sasl=supersavingsdeals&_sop=12&_dmd=1&_ipg=200&_fosrp=1',
    method : 'GET',
    headers : {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
}

const pageLinks = [];

async function getPagesRecursive(link) {
    await request(link, (error, response, html) => {
        if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const nextPage = $('td.pagn-next > a').attr('href');
            pageLinks.push(link)
            if(nextPage) {
                return getPagesRecursive(nextPage);
            }
            console.log(pageLinks);
        }
    })
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's nothing for you Javascript and Node.js experts ;) I've posted it to you using async/await, but I would like to use promises with the request module, since I feel I know them better and personally, I've tried every other way unsuccessfully :)

I've provided you guys two urls to try in the options object for the request module. The first one is a link to a seller with multiple items, and it should get all the page links. The 2nd link is a seller with only one page, and it should get only that seller's one page link.

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Don't pass a callback to `request`. Use promises, i.e. `then` or `await`! Please show us how you tried to use them.

Comment: I tried the solution of user trincot, but apparently the link is auto-generated by clicking the next page button . I don't think it is since I looked at the page source and the link is already there . I just can't access it for some reason :(

Answer (score 1):

As `request` returns a promise, you don't need to use the callback, nor the `async` `await` syntax -- just return the promise.

Also, instead of populating a global `pageLinks` array, it is nicer if you build the array of links based on the values that the promises fulfill with.

```
function getPagesRecursive(link) {
    return request(link).then(html => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const nextPage = $('td.pagn-next > a').attr('href');
        return nextPage ? getPagesRecursive(nextPage).then(links => [link, ...links])
                        : [link];
    });
}

// Use:
getPagesRecursive(firstPage).then(links => console.log(links))
                            .catch(err => console.log("request failed", err));
```

Comment: Wow your answer is elegant, I like it !  If this works, you're saving my life and I'm awarding you maximum points or something ! 

Comment: When I try to use it with the 2nd link (the link with only 1 page), it works . But when I try to use it with the 1sr link (the link with multiple pages), it throws me a request failed { RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "javascript:;"

Comment: That is because apparently the page has a `<a href="javascript:;">` element, so it does not have a real http URL. You would need to exclude such cases with a bit more code. If that is a problem, then you are out of luck: the next URL is dynamically determined by the JavaScript on that page.

Comment: Can't I just set a timeout or something to wait for it to appear and then get it ?

Comment: No, because the `href` attribute would not change. It is when the user *clicks* on that link that code is executed that then performs the navigation. You would need a whole different and much more complex solution if you would need to mimic that. It involves installing a headless browser API so you can interact with a page. That honestly goes way beyond what I could answer here.

Comment: I know how to install a headless browser . I have puppeteer installed right now . The problem is, it's slow :( . Look at the 2nd link's page source . You will see a td with class of page-next with an anchor tag and the link that is already there . I don't think the link is auto generated since I didn't even click on the next page button and it already shows up

Comment: I looked at that source, but I don't even see a `pagn-next` class. Maybe because I am no ebay user, and pages are generated differently then.

Comment: It seems that the links look similar. If I can figure out the pattern, I'll be able to generate future links. In any case, your solution works, so I am eternally grateful ;)